# Array max value function gives unexpected result

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, max

I have this function for returning the maximum value of an array:

```
Array.prototype.max = function() {

var max = this[0];
var len = this.length;

for (var i = 1; i < len; i++)
{

    if (this[i] > max)
    {       
        max = this[i];
    }
}

    return max;
}
```

When I use this array:

```
var data1Values = ['0','0','0','0','3','0','6','12']
```

`data1Values.max()` returns 6 instead of 12. It somehow skips the last value.

I've inserted `alert(this[i])` and `alert(max)` inside the loop, and it recognizes both values (12 as `this[i]` and 6 as `max`) but it wont enter the condition.

What is happening here ?

Comment: You can use `Math.max` with `.apply` to get the max from an Array. `Math.max.apply(null, data1Values);`, so if you want the function on `Array.prototype`, do this... `Array.prototype.max = function() { return Math.max.apply(null, this); };`

Comment: I was wondering if that was possible. Why not add as answer?

Comment: @mplungjan: Because it doesn't technically answer the question being asked. Just wanted to offer it as an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing strings. "2" is greater than "1000"

Change to numbers or add parseInt(this[i],10)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/cnP22/)

```
Array.prototype.max = function() {

  var len = this.length;
  var max = -1;
  for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
    var val = parseInt(this[i],10);
    if (val > max) {       
        max = val;
    }
  }

  return max;
}

var data1Values = ['0','0','0','0','3','0','6','12']

alert(data1Values.max());
```

Answer (score 7):

You've got an array of **strings**, not numbers. The string "6" is greater than the string "12".

Try initializing your array without the quotes around the values.

Comment: Because the ordering of the numeric symbols is the same as the numeric ordering; that is, the character '9' has a larger code value than the character '8'.  For multi-digit strings of numeric characters, however, if the first characters differ then the larger one determines the larger string value. It's like how the word "apple" goes before "cat" in the dictionary; 'a' is smaller than 'c' and that is all that matters.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer :)